# My mails don't reach destination on my mail server iRedmail using sogo webmail

Tags: iredmail

I configure a mail server called iRedmail and now I have a problem I can't send messages and I can't receive message. I use a webmail called sogo mail which came with the configuration of iRedmail. I would like getting your help. Thank you

I try to send messages using sogo webmail but messages don't reach the destination